# Win32 API Events- What are its limitations in terms of access across different processes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, ipc

So, I have an application which hooks up to a library that handles a number of different tasks in different threads.

In one thread of the library, which is **not** the library's main thread, an event is created.

However, when I try to open the event from the application which uses the library itself, I always receive an invalid `HANDLE`.

The event does not use a private namespace, nor does it have any options specified for Win32's kernel object namespaces - it's pretty default.

In fact, here is the function which is used to create the event within the library thread:

`CreateEventA(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, eventName);`

A later call within the same thread to open the event with the following parameters is valid:

`OpenEventA(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, eventName); // returns event without issue`

Furthermore, according to MSDN, the following is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx):

`The creating thread can also specify a name for the event object.` **`Threads in other processes can open a handle to an existing event object by specifying its name in a call to the OpenEvent function.`**

Apparently this isn't a mistake, either, given that the same gist is repeated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684123(v=vs.85).aspx):

`The process that creates an object can use the handle returned by the creation function (CreateEvent, CreateMutex, CreateSemaphore, or CreateWaitableTimer).`**`Other processes can open a handle to the object by using its name, or through inheritance or duplication.`**

I've looked through MSDN to find something which would explicitly state scenarios in which this would not be the case, and I have yet to find anything.

I can also state that I've seen the event active in the library's thread when querying for the event within the application - which, as far I can see, rules out the possibility of it simply not being created.

Can someone shed some light on why the event returns NULL from `OpenEvent` when queried via the application?

**Update**

In response to @FrerichRaabe:

The error code returned is 2, or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

@IInspectable:

Interesting; I forgot to mention that I actually have tried using the global namespace for the event, which obviously didn't work either. The same error as mentioned above is what's returned as well...

Comment: Access is controlled through [Access Control Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872.aspx). Other than that, events can be accessed from any process running in the same session. If the event is created in the global namespace, it is accessible from any process running in the system.

Comment: Well, what does `GetLastError()` return after `OpenEvent()` returns null?

Comment: I've updated the post in response to both of your comments. @IInspectable I'll be sure to look into the ACL info, thanks.

Comment: There's little reason to assume that the error code isn't accurate.  The plain explanation is that the event simply doesn't exist.  Because you are trying to open it before it was created, a pretty common mishap with threaded code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by 2 unfortunate decisions: Using an event with non-ASCII characters in its name, and calling the ANSI version of the API (indicated by the trailing `A`).

Since the system uses Unicode internally, whenever you call an ANSI API, string parameters are converted to Unicode. The conversion of non-ASCII characters is controlled by the thread's current locale. This explains, why a call to `OpenEventA` on the same thread succeeds, while a it fails on another thread.

To solve this, replace the calls to the ANSI APIs with their respective Unicode versions `CreateEventW` and `OpenEventW`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the EVENT_ALL_ACCESS flag. Do you really need it?
Usually "SYNCHRONIZE | EVENT_MODIFY_STATE" is sufficient for events.

Try that and let us know.

Comment: That didn't work, either. I also tried SYNCHRONIZE by itself, along with READ_CONTROL. Neither worked.

Comment: Is one process running elevated and the other non-elevated?

Comment: Error code 2 (FILE_NOT_FOUND) indicates that the name wasn't found. Are you sure the event name is the same between the two calls? You didn't mix up ANSI and Unicode, by any chance did you? (I notice you're using the ANSI APIs which is unusual these days). One other thing: Is the first process running elevated but not the second? (I think you'd get ACCESS_DENIED for that, but maybe not)